# What is the average depth of the ocean?

Tags: oceanography, bathymetry

We know that the ocean depth is varies from ocean to ocean. Mariana trench is about 11 km deep. If we consider as a whole, what is the average depth of the ocean?

Comment: The average depth of the Pacific Ocean or of the global oceans?

Comment: It is global ocean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About four kilometers, see, for example:
http://www.mbgnet.net/salt/oceans/data.htm 
But bear in mind that much of the oceans, especially in the southern hemisphere, have scarcely been mapped at all, so it is currently impossible to give an accurate estimate.

Comment: Surprised.  Would think they'd send wavelengths that are scattered by rock but not water from satellites and get a pretty solid picture.

Answer (score 2):

From NOAA: (Official US Science) A recent estimate for the average depth of the ocean is 3,682 meters, or 12,080 feet.
This is an estimate from 2010. Older estimates have deeper average ocean.

Comment: please provide a link to your source